# Change angular material multi select's selected values css

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change material multi select selected values css.

```
                <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                    <mat-select placeholder="Kullanıcı Yetkileri" [(value)]="selectedPermissions" multiple>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let permission of filteredPermissions | async" [value]="permission">{{permission.name}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

When I inspect the selected values in the browser source code I see like this:

```
<span class="ng-tns-c22-16 ng-star-inserted">selection-1,selection-2</span>
```

So I want to set a css class to selected values by wrapping a `span`.

How can I change css of material multi select's selected values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but probably you will need to disable the Encapsulation of the  component who contains the `<mat-form-field>`

On your `@Component` decorator add:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

That way you can inspect the component with your Browser inspector and write the appropriate CSS rules.